# PeopleSoft Webserver crashing, losing connection to AppServer

Tags: sockets, crash, webserver, peoplesoft

On our Webserver, we're seeing a ton of these errors:

Application Server last connected //psoftapp.company.net_8850
bea.jolt.ServiceException: bea.jolt.JoltRemoteService(GetCertificate)call(): Timeout\nbea.jolt.SessionException: Connection recv error\nbea.jolt.JoltException: [3] NwHdlr.recv(): Timeout Error

and on our Appserver:

PSPUBDSP_dflt.27505 (0) 07/20/11 08:13:33 (JNIUTIL): Java exception thrown: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

I'm reading some tuning documents from PeopleSoft & I found a suggestion that I've seen in a couple of places -- Reducing the tcp_wait_time_interval to 60 seconds.  I think I sort of understand what this is doing - It seems that network (or socket?) connections that are no longer being used are "recycled" or made available?  Can someone confirm this?  Also, why are these connections unused/stale?  Is it caused by people not properly logging out of the app (and just closing the browser)?

Thanks!

Comment: I can tell you that it's NOT caused by people not properly logging out. That will not cause your webserver to crash.

Perhaps you have an incorrectly coded component that's either hanging or taking a long while to process.

Answer (score 0):

PSPUBDP is part of the Integration Broker application messaging framework. You could look at the Tuxedo logs or the Integration Broker Monitor too see what is going on. You may be running a high number of messages and overloading the server or possibly you have a message with errors that is somehow causing the crashes.